# How to set gasLimit manually when calling function over ABI

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js

My question is pretty simple, but I am a newbie.

We have 2 ways to call functions over ethers js. 1) over ABI 2)
directly to contract address and encode data to send. I have script
that can set gasLimit in option 2 but it is not convenient. I want to
set gasLimit when I use 1st option. This is my scripts. Where I can
set gasLimit here?

```
> const hre = require("hardhat") const Artifact =
> require("../artifacts/contracts/Tmp.sol/Tmp.json") const ethers =
> hre.ethers /* global BigInt */
> 
> 

async function main () {
    >     
    >     const targetA = '0x610178dA211FEF7D417bC0e6FeD39F05609AD788';
    >     const accountAddr ='0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266';
    >     
    > 
    >     const signer = ethers.provider.getSigner(accountAddr);
    >     const targetC = new ethers.Contract(targetA, Artifact.abi, signer);
    > 
    >     const contractCall0 = await targetC.add() //add - the name of function.
    >     console.log(contractCall0);
    > 
    > }
    > 
    >     main()
    >     .then(() => process.exit(0))
    >     .catch(error => {
    >       console.error(error);
    >       process.exit(1);
    >     });
```

BTW, sometimes it's working sometimes not. As I detect, when I dont manually add gasLimit - hardhat set not enough gasLimit to execute tx.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set the gasLimit as the last argument of the call, like so:

```
const contractCall0 = await targetC.add({
  gasLimit: 100000,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the `gasLimit` when using the first option, you can do it by passing the `gasLimit` option in the transaction parameters when calling the function. The `gasLimit` determines the maximum amount of gas that the Ethereum network will allow to be used for executing the transaction.

Here's how you can set the `gasLimit` in your script:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");
const Artifact = require("../artifacts/contracts/Tmp.sol/Tmp.json");
const ethers = hre.ethers;

async function main() {
  const targetA = '0x610178dA211FEF7D417bC0e6FeD39F05609AD788';
  const accountAddr = '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266';
  
  const signer = ethers.provider.getSigner(accountAddr);
  const targetC = new ethers.Contract(targetA, Artifact.abi, signer);

  // Specify the gasLimit in the options object
  const options = { gasLimit: 1000000 }; // Set the appropriate gas limit value

  const contractCall0 = await targetC.add(options); // add - the name of the function.
  console.log(contractCall0);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

In the example above, I set the `gasLimit` to `1000000` as an example. You should adjust this value based on the complexity of your contract and the estimated gas consumption for the function you are calling.

Hope this will be helpful to u.